# What's the purpose of the ui.theme directory in a Jetpack Compose project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The actual colors, which are used for e.g. the top-bar, are still defined in 'res'/'values'.

Modifying the values in 'ui.theme'/'Color.kt' shows no effect.

Currently confused about the 'ui.theme'-directory. **Does someone know, where these constants are used?**

Comment: Not really. Check this link. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3